# Не могу запустить контейнер Sentry.io

Tags: docker, debian

Решил поставить себе sentry.io. Все делаю по официальной инструкции - [вот она](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/)

Запускаю установку `./install.sh` и получаю такую ошибку

```
Step 1/5 : ARG BASE_IMAGE
Step 2/5 : FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
 ---> cda5760ce0b7
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends cron &&     rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 74cbb5d9ba80
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package cron
Removing intermediate container 74cbb5d9ba80
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends cron &&     rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
Service 'snuba-cleanup' failed to build : Build failed
An error occurred, caught SIGERR on line 4
Cleaning up...
```

Насколько я понял, в docker контейнере не работает сеть. Пробовал разные решения - ничего не помогает.

Может кто сталкивался - помогите советом

Comment: А не в контейнере, просто с сервера url доступны?

Comment: @PotroNik, да, сам сервер работает без проблем

Comment: судя [по](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61567404/4827341), первое, что стоит опробовать — перезапуск демона docker. вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24991136/4827341) ещё больше всяких разных советов.

Comment: перегружать пробовал - все так же. и все советы тоже пробовал - нету результата